# error while locating my current location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude, android-maps-v2

I am developing application to get my current location on the map and display the nearest places.
first my application was running but the camera goes at fixed Latlng ( i put the values) but when i change the code to make the camera on my current location .. my phone shutting down.
This is my logcat:

```
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at     com.example.buttontest.NearbyActivity.onConnected(NearbyActivity.java:219)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.v(Unknown Source)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$f.a(Unknown Source)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$f.a(Unknown Source)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$b.A(Unknown Source)
 11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-09 08:38:51.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is where the error

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Comment: because your latLng is null as the location.getLatitude() & location.getLongitude() returning null..

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` is thrown because there might be a possibility that the `location` you got here `Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();` is `null`. Hence you might always do a null-check.